# Exporting Slick table in PlaySlick DAO

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

The code below is a PlaySlick sample that demonstrates a DAO class. I used this as a sample, however my issue is that I use the same table (for example, the `CatTable` class) in more than one DAO, and since the table is an inner class, I cannot import it in other DAOs as it's not in a companion object. Is there a way to fix this?

```
package dao

import scala.concurrent.Future

import javax.inject.Inject
import models.Cat
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.db.slick.HasDatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

class CatDAO @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) 
                   extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  private val Cats = TableQuery[CatsTable]

  def all(): Future[Seq[Cat]] = db.run(Cats.result)

  def insert(cat: Cat): Future[Unit] = db.run(Cats += cat).map { _ => () }

  private class CatsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Cat](tag, "CAT") {

    def name = column[String]("NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
    def color = column[String]("COLOR")

    def * = (name, color) <> (Cat.tupled, Cat.unapply _)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Classic approach we often use is this:

```
// student course segment
  case class StudentCourseSegment(studentId: Id[Student],
                                  courseId: Id[Course],
                                  semesterId: Id[Semester],
                                  id: Id[StudentCourseSegment] = Id.none)

  class StudentCourseSegmentTable(tag: Tag) extends 
    Table[StudentCourseSegment](tag, "STUDENT_COURSE_SEGMENT") {
    def studentId = column[Id[Student]]("STUDENT_ID")
    def courseId = column[Id[Course]]("COURSE_ID")
    def semesterId = column[Id[Semester]]("SEMESTER_ID")
    def id = column[Id[StudentCourseSegment]]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def * = (studentId, courseId, semesterId, id) <> (StudentCourseSegment.tupled, 
                                                      StudentCourseSegment.unapply)

    // foreign keys
    def student = foreignKey("fk_segment_student", studentId, StudentTable)(_.id)
    def course = foreignKey("fk_segment_course", courseId, CourseTable)(_.id)
    def semester = foreignKey("fk_segment_semester", semesterId, SemesterTable)(_.id)
  }

  lazy val StudentCourseSegmentTable = TableQuery[StudentCourseSegmentTable]
```

(example from my presentation: http://slides.com/pdolega/slick-101#/69)

So you have (on the same level):

- case class - aka *unpacked type* (your domain in application)
- table definition - aka *mixed type*
- table query object

Your main DAO for this table will use this definitions, but so will other DAOs (e.g. for doing `joins`).

Point here I guess is this: **nothing forces you to keep `TableQuery` (or other mentioned artifacts) as private inner members / classes**. You can keep them as inner classes, as top level classes in same file or entirely somewhere else.

Also one thing - not related to the question but I see it in your example. I'd suggest to stay on `DBIO` level as in your `DAO` classes; if you transform everything instantly to `Future`s you loose composability (you won't be able to perform multiple operations in same transaction).

Comment: thanks, but I still have the problem. I have two options: to declare the table definition outside the DAO (in that case, I don't know how to import the api) or to somehow have access to the inner class. I prefer the first method, but how to import the api? If you take a look, the import is INSIDE the class, that's the reason I cannot define the table definition independently. By the way, this code is taken from the PlaySlick example, if it's better to use DBIO then they should update it.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/computer-database/app/dao/CompaniesDAO.scala) I have another example of declaring a table definition in PlaySlick. Since it's inside a trait, I cannot use it in a different DAO because the trait is hidden.

Comment: Well... that's easy: just import what you need, like here: https://gist.github.com/pdolega/359797842c4f15cfb35b10a2be8d2e39 (see import in line 9: `import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._` ?).

I repeat again - no one forces you to put table definitions inside inner class or trait or whatever. It's really artificial problem - put it in a place which is suitable for you. As for examples - they keep it that way because it's the simplest thing (put everything in a single class / trait and done).

Comment: As for play-slick example and returning `Future`s in `DAO`. They basically do the simplest thing that proves that it works (and which is easy to comprehend). They are not necessarily showing you how to build real application. 


I guess you are welcome to update their samples, though play-slick is not really a very active project - last update 7 months ago. Keep in mind play-slick is really a tiny helper project - if you strip samples, docs etc it's only a handful of classes.

Comment: Last but not least - please take a look here: https://github.com/pdolega/slick-101 . You have there answers to all above questions. Simply clone the repo an run `./activator test` (you don't need anything to install it). I tried to make it an easy way to start with Slick 3.x

Comment: I can import any api (such as H2Profile) in compilation time and in run time it will use  PlaySlick pool management seamlessly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129840/discussion-between-pawel-dolega-and-ps0604).